# Calling bunch of REST APIs in distributed environment

Tags: rest, architecture, microservices, distributed-computing, distributed

I have my application logic in a python library. Each operation provided by my library involves calling some REST api one or more times. So I have:

```
def OperationA(resource_id, params):

   Call REST Api /X/resource_id/params
   Call REST Api /Y/resource_id/params
   Call REST Api /Z/resource_id/params

def OperationB(resource_id params):

   Call REST Api /R/resource_id//params
   Call REST Api /S/resource_id//params
   Call REST Api /T/resource_id//params
```

The library is executing in a distributed environment and operations are called in response to user actions. So it's possible that for example two instances of OperationA are executing concurrently. It's acceptable to run an operation concurrently if the executions are affecting different resources. However calls to operation that are affecting same resource should be executed sequentially. That is because interleaving calls to REST api can result in inconsistent state at the REST service. For example this could happen if OperationA is executed concurrently on resource with id 3:

```
OperationA(3, "foo"): Call REST Api /X/3/foo
OperationA(3, "bla"): Call REST Api /X/3/bla
OperationA(3, "bla"): Call REST Api /Y/3/bla
OperationA(3, "foo"): Call REST Api /Y/3/foo
OperationA(3, "foo"): Call REST Api /Z/3/foo
OperationA(3, "bla"): Call REST Api /Z/3/bla
```

The problem is that in the end resource 3 at endpoint Y is in state foo whereas at all other endpoints resource is in state bla.

I could acquire distributed lock before calling REST api but I would need also support from the REST api itself as [Martin Kleppmann pointed out](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html) (in form of fencing token) which is not possible as I have no control over the REST api.

Is there some existing technology/service that could be used prevent unacceptable concurrent executing and still be able to scale the service horizontally?

Comment: What are the semantics of your calls to X/Y/Z/R/S/T? For example, if your `OperationA` will e.g. read `X`, `Y` and then set something in `Z`; but this is only correct if the value in `X` hasn't changed?

Answer (score 2):

If you control all the clients accessing this API, you can try and serialize all accesses to the same resource through [consistent hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing) -- a given resource will always be handled by the same machine and then you'll only need to acquire a local lock.

If there are other clients accessing this API concurrently, and the API doesn't offer enough *expressiveness* for your operations (e.g. only allowing to set `A` to `10`, rather than allowing to say increment `A` by `1`), nor any conditional/test-and-set updates (e.g. set `A` to `10` if its previous value is `9`), nor multi-key transactions (e.g. increment `A` by `1` and decrement `B` by 2) nor locks… you may be out of luck as there is no way of guaranteeing the properties you want.